# undefined method `url' for "#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8b6134d610>":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave to upload picture, after uploaded, I got the error when go to show page:

```
undefined method `url' for "#ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8b6134d610>":String
<%= image_tag @product.picture.url if @product.picture? %>
```

Here is my code:

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  </div>
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader  
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @product.name %>
</p>
  <strong>Picture:</strong>
  <%= image_tag @product.picture.url if @product.picture? %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

**Update:**

picture_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Here is the version in Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.5.1'
gem 'fog',                     '1.38.0'
```

Comment: can you show `PictureUploader`?

Comment: as understood, image gets uploaded? You see it in your 'public/uploads' folder? And try to set this in enviroment.rb - `require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'`

Answer (score 0):

I would check first strong params and add `:picture` attribute if it hasn't been added.

Then I would try to add this in your show views:

show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag(@product.picture_url.to_s) %>
```

instead of this line of code:

```
<%= image_tag @product.picture.url if @product.picture? %>
```

In case that you have permissions problem, you can create config file:

```
config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
```

and add permissions:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.directory_permissions = 0777
  config.storage = :file
end
```

Answer (score -1):

in model, you need add

> Blockquote
> mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
> Blockquote

Comment: it's already there - see the `product.rb` they posted.