# Referred CarrierWave's official documentation but image not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am developing a project in Ruby on Rails and I have to upload an image for it. I came across CarrierWave for that, and hence I referred its official documentation for it. However, when I upload an image, the image is getting stored in the database but when I try to display it with `<%= image_tag @books.cover.url %>` I get the following error:

```
undefined method `url' for "#ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000e983c68>":String
```

Please find the code for the files below:

**app/views/books/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: book, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if book.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(book.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this book from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% book.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :cover %>
    <%= form.file_field :cover %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**app/models/book.rb**

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :library

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**app/views/books/show.html.erb**

```
<p>
    <strong>Cover:</strong>
    <%= image_tag @book.cover.url if @book.cover? %>
</p>
```

**app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    #ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
      "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpeg png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

**Gemfile**

```
# Upload Images
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
```

Ruby Version: 2.6.4

Rails Version: 6.0.0

I read a few questions on StackOverflow as well for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321416/undefined-method-url-for-actiondispatchhttpuploadedfile0x007f8b6134d61), but no solution worked for me. I even tried reading a few online tutorials for CarrierWave but they use the same code as I do and yet the code works for them but not for me.
Please let me know if anyone has encountered this before or if you require any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to mount the uploader for `:cover`.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :library
    mount_uploader :cover, ImageUploader
end
```

Comment: Damn it! It was a very stupid mistake on my part. Thanks a lot.